# Does Google WorkSpace support unsolicited IdP-initiated SSO with a deep link target resource or relay state endpoint URL?

Tags: google-workspace, idp

Does Google WorkSpace support unsolicited IdP-initiated SSO with a deep link target resource or relay state endpoint URL?

Answer (score 0):

I couldnt find a google document about this, however based on our test results and AWS support it does not.